# PyCharm does not properly identify requirements

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

These are the contents of my `requirements.txt`:

```
» cat requirements.txt 
dse-driver
```

These are my currently installed requirements:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> names = [pkg.project_name for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set]
>>> print(names)

[..., 'dse-driver', ... ]
```

And this is my code:

```
import dse

...
```

`PyCharm 2020.3` complains about `dse` not being listed in my requirements file, which is not correct: it is listed, but it has a different name. I can not help it.

If I follow `PyCharm` advice to automatically "Add imported packages to requirements", it does the following:

```
dse-driver

setuptools~=50.3.2
```

Which makes no sense!

How can I make `PyCharm` realize that the `dse` module corresponds to the `dse-driver` package in the requirements?

Comment: You sure it's PyCharm and not the `requirements` plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe at some point one of PyCharm developers scraped PyPI and made a list of package name mappings. It is stored in `<PyCharm>/plugins/python/lib/tools/packages` file.

You can add your package there as a quick workaround.

Here is the corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27985